# Rails Get Nested Relationship as ActiveRecord object without collect/map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

As an example:

A `company has_many employees`

an `employee has_many tasks`

I want to get all the tasks in descending order.  Ideally, I'd like to do something like `Company.all.employees.tasks.order('created_at desc')`.  Unfortunately, by the time I get through `employees`, I now have an array of ActiveRecord objects.  I've been running into this issue for a while, and I've just been using `map` and `collect`, but sorting in descending order makes for more overhead than I want.  This can be done with a SQL query so I'm sure I can do it in ActiveRecord, but my research hasn't helped much.

EDIT:
The solution should work for any number of models.  For example, if a `task has_many items` and an `item has_many sub_items` ad infinitum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach you can use is to use `through`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :employees
   has_many :tasks, through: :employees
end
```

Then a `Company` will have `tasks` for all of it's employees.
c
Another way to do it would be to use joins.  So assuming that a `Task` `belongs_to` a `Employee` and an `Employee` `belongs_to` a `Company`

```
c = Company.first # for a company...
tasks = Task.where(companies:{id: c.id}).joins(employee: :company)
```

So I am asking for all tasks where the `companies` table (and yes it is the table in the where). We use the joins to establish the tables that must be joined to.

Comment: The reason I'm not a huge fan of this one is that it gets cumbersome with many nested attributes.  I used a simple example here, but in the case that this is 4+ levels deep, it breaks down a bit

Comment: Edited the answer with a non through approach.